# IIS: Download large file with wget - connection always fails with Bitrate Throottling

Tags: asp.net, iis, wget, large-files, bitrate

I have a problem to make IIS to allow download file with Bitrate Throottling. I set limit file to 100kb/s. There is no problem without bitrate limitation. But with limit I have a problem.
I'm using a code similar to described in this article:
[Securing Large Downloads Using C# and IIS 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2178984/securing-large-downloads-using-c-sharp-and-iis-7)

I also tried to switch off IIS Bitrate Throottling and control bitrate "by hand" calculating with TimeSpan the bitrate and using Thread.Sleep(10) in a while...

But all my tries was useless, I don't get any exceptions.

to test download I use wget, this way:

```
wget -t 1 http://db.realestate.ru/yrl/RealEstateExportToYandex.xml
```

(you can try it with wget for windows)

this is a 240Mb text file, wget always stops, at random position of downloading, 5% - 60% and throws this error message:

> Read error at byte ... (Connection reset by peer).

May be the problem is not with IIS, because in may localhost is working well, but not online on highly loaded server.

Answer (score 1):

Solved with this parameters specified in wget command:

```
wget -t 1 --header="Keep-Alive: 30000" -nv http://db.realestate.ru/yrl/RealEstateExportToYandex.xml
```