# How to disable Server GC in ASP.NET Framework App running on Azure App Service

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, garbage-collection, azure-web-app-service

I'm doing some high density hosting of ASP.NET MVC 5 / WCF apps on Azure App Service and the idle apps are using 600~1000MB of memory each which is quite a lot, given that a memory dump reveals that the GC heap is only about ~40MB full.
I suspect this is due to server GC so i tried disabling it by following https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/file-schema/runtime/gcserver-element
and adding

```
<gcServer enabled="false" />
```

to my web.config, but this does not appear to have any effect as

```
GCSettings.IsServerGC
```

is still returning true. What am i missing here?

EDIT:

Using normal IIS it can be done using https://weblogs.asp.net/owscott/setting-an-aspnet-config-file-per-application-pool but in Azure App Service, you lack the permissions to do this.

Comment: What is the problem you think you have?   Apps using too much memory?  Sounds to me like you think you have a problem but you don't.

Comment: @Neil as i've explained, the apps are using up to a 1GB of memory, doing nothing and as i've analyzed, the GC heap has only about 40MB of utilization. Server GC is known to have a higher memory footprint than workstation GC so having more efficient memory utilization is more important than the benefits of server gc for me in this case.

Comment: If they do not really use it then while they claim it, it is not really there. Which means you hunt ghosts (reservation not usage).

Comment: @TomTom i mean, it still takes up physical resources in my App Service Plan which is at like 80% memory utilization. It's just not used effectively.

Comment: Did you set your `web.config` property `copy to Output directory` as `copy always` when publish  app to azure?  If  not, it will not work with gcServer .

Comment: The question is *How to enable/disable Server GC in Azure?* but you're trying to solve a potential memory leak. I thighly recommend you go through this very similar QA: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25993290/mvc-asp-net-is-using-a-lot-of-memory

Comment: @JoeyCai yes, i've verified that the config is deployed correctly by going to the app service editor and inspect the `web.config` there.

Comment: @JeremyThompson yes the behavior is quite similiar to that question, that's why i want to switch to workstation GC which acts way more aggressive in keeping the heap size down, contrary to server GC which permits quite large heaps to reduce collection frequency.

Comment: it seems this setting doesn't work anymore for ASP.NET. I've tried and it doesn't even work in my local environment.  It works fine for ASP.NET Core though.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, first of all, it seems like you might have to manually debug the memory usage of components using GC.Collect():
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.gc.collect?view=netcore-3.1

This way you might be able to pinpoint a specific part of the code that either causes a memory leak due to bad garbage collection, or parts that are using certain third-party libraries.

Once you are done with this quite tedious part, then depending on what you think is causing the problem, you should consider either using a manual disposal of the code block utilizing `(using var item = new NameOfClass())`  or even trying ti implement `IDispose` on the classes that are causing it: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/implementing-dispose.